# SimpleCursorAdapter doesn't return any object in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I use SimpleCursorAdapter in my app to get rows from db , I do not receive any error, I tryed to put the values in the db but I can't see any filled listview. I post my code below for better explanation.

**FragmentTab2.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab2, container, false);

    d= new Database(getActivity());
    Cursor c = d.getBarcode();

    CursorLoader(c);

    String from[] = {Codice.DATI_ID,
            Codice.DATI_BARCODE};

    int to[] = {R.id.record_id,
            R.id.record_barcode};

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(view.getContext(),
            R.layout.singolo_elemento_card,
            c, from, to);
    cardBarcode = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.barcode_list);
    cardBarcode.setAdapter(sca);


    cardBarcode.setClickable(true);
    cardBarcode.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {


        }
    });
    return view;
}
private void CursorLoader(Cursor c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

in my **Database.java**:

```
 public Cursor getBarcode(){

        Cursor c= db.query(Codice.TABLE_CARD, null , 
                    null , 
                    null , 
                    null , 
                    null ,  
                    null );
         return c;
 }
```

Comment: use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor()` in `getBarcode` to see it on the logcat

Comment: show `CursorLoader` method code also

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK CursorLoader method is at the bottom and is empty

Comment: and what you see on the logcat?

Comment: @pskink 08-05 12:31:46.975: I/System.out(15604): >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@408a39a0
08-05 12:31:46.975: I/System.out(15604): <<<<<

Comment: so its empty: thats why you see nothing in the list view

Comment: you can make sure its empty by calling `Log.d` with `cursor.getCount()`

Comment: @pskink it give me 0

Comment: yes i know: its empty

Comment: @pskink so what I can do?

Comment: @pskink I have already add data

Comment: no: your table is empty: use adb shell and run `sqlite3` tool with your database: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html